# (Why) Should not the request parameters be accessed directly in controllers of a Yii application?

Tags: php, yii, get, httprequest, http-request-parameters

There are several ways to access the request parameters within a controller:

**direcly**

```
class MyController extends \CController
{
    ...
    public function actionMy()
    {
        ...
        $myVar = $_GET['my_param'];
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**over the request object**

```
class MyController extends \CController
{
    ...
    public function actionMy()
    {
        ...
        $myVar = $this->request->params('my_param');
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

(Why) Is the variant with the request object better?

Comment: What about Yii::app()->request->getParam('my_param') ?

Comment: What do you mean with "what about ..."? Yes, it's also possible and it's still the second variant (over the request object).

Answer (score 1):

The web Request class represents an HTTP request it encapsulates the $_SERVER variable and resolves its inconsistency among different Web servers.

```
/**
 * Returns the named GET or POST parameter value.
 * If the GET or POST parameter does not exist, the second parameter to this method will be returned.
 * If both GET and POST contains such a named parameter, the GET parameter takes precedence.
 * @param string $name the GET parameter name
 * @param mixed $defaultValue the default parameter value if the GET parameter does not exist.
 * @return mixed the GET parameter value
 * @see getQuery
 * @see getPost
 */
public function getParam($name,$defaultValue=null)
{
    return isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : (isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! But what is the advantage of this approach?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you the actual source code. Basically the advantage is that it will check both get and post, you can set a default value, and it does an isset.